# find a rectangle limited to 4 lines

Tags: geometry, 3d, rectangles, programming

I want to find `center` of rectangle given `w = width` and `h = height`. The rectangle is limited to 4 lines:

[image]

as you see, all of lines `cross trough (0, 0, 0)`. I know unit vector of each lines (a, b, c, and d). So each point on each line can be shown as:

[image]

where `a(i), b(i), c(i), and d(i) are unit vectors of L1, L2, L3, and L4`, respectively.

My questions are:

1- How can I calculate point `C` (`center of rectangle`)? 
2- How can I calculate points `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, and `P4`? 
3- Are the points (center and other) `unique?`

Any `pseudo code` or real code in `Matlab`, `C++`, `C`, or `Python` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since vectors $a,b,c,d$ are known, then to specify the rectangle you have four unknowns which are $t_1, t_2 , t_3, t_4 $.  We can assume that $t_1 = 1$ and this will generate all the rectangles parallel to it in space.  Now, $t_2, t_3, t_4$ need to satisfy the following orthogonality conditons:

$ P_1 P_2 \perp P_1 P_4 $

$ P_2 P_1 \perp P_2 P_3 $

$ P_3 P_2 \perp P_3 P_4 $

The above equations translate to

$ (\mathbf{b} t_2 - \mathbf{a} ) \cdot ( \mathbf{d} t_4 - \mathbf{a} ) = 0 $

$ (\mathbf{b} t_2 - \mathbf{a} ) \cdot ( \mathbf{c} t_3 - \mathbf{b} t_2 ) = 0 $

$ ( \mathbf{c} t_3 - \mathbf{b} t_2 ) \cdot ( \mathbf{d} t_4 - \mathbf{c} t_3 ) = 0 $

These nonlinear equations can be solved numerically.

Comment: I wrote a program in Matlab using `fmincon` with 4 params (t1, t2, ...). It works correctly. I remove `t1` and `set to 1` as you said but it does not answer correctly as I expect.

Comment: fmincon is used for minimization.  What are you minimizing ?